# vector3.movetowards moving immediately instead of step by step

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

im working on a script to make my ggameobject jump towards another ggameobject at a speed higher than my movespeed

```
 IEnumerator Qjump()
    {
        float step = 1f * Time.deltaTime;
        while (Vector3.Distance(positionofenemy, transform.position) > 1)
        {

            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, positionofenemy, 1 * Time.deltaTime);
        }
       
        
      
        yield return null;
        

    }
```

so when I call the coroutine Qjump my game object to movetowards the other gameobject until their distance is the distance between them is at 1 or lower, however when i call the coroutine it instead just jumps my gameobject straight to the other gameobject

Answer (score 1):

Your `yield return` should *also* be located within the `while` loop:

```cs
IEnumerator Qjump()
{
    float step = 1f * Time.deltaTime;
    while (Vector3.Distance(positionofenemy, transform.position) > 1)
    {

        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, positionofenemy, 1 * Time.deltaTime);

        yield return null; // make sure we don't go the whole way and return every iteration
    }

    yield return null;
}
```

The reason for this is becuase when you work with `IEnumerator` each `yield return null`(in this case) is treated as a distinct step. If you don't place one within the `while` loop, the whole loop finishes before the first 'step'.

Comment: You are right. Just to some more details to your answer, MoveTowards is resource-intensive. For 'Lee Geng' problem, 'Vector3.Lerp' is much more suited and performant.

Comment: Actually that very last `yield return null;` is unnecessary

Comment: Yeah, but I wasn't sure if OP was going to extend the method to do other things, and I didn't want to remove anything that wasn't directly related to the problem. But it is 100% not doing anything. The compiler 100% removes it at compile time, I hope.